# Need to print the columns in same order using AWK

Tags: awk

I am having a file which is space delimited with two or more as shown below:

```
r_q01     smip_sc_rq0_t   r_uq02  
r_q02     super_path77/dfpp_tcdxa1_t   umc3  
r_q02     super_path3/dfppoi_tcdxa1_t   r_q01  
r_q03     super_0/cbo_bqibif0_t   ntb0  
r_q0367     super_top_0/nbio_nbif0_t   nbif4
```

I want to print the column in same order and I tried below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F'  +' '{print $1 "        " $2 "                                                      " $3}' file.txt
```

My output:

```
r_q01        smip_sc_rq0_t                                                      r_uq02
r_q02        super_path77/dfpp_tcdxa1_t                                                      umc3
r_q02        super_path3/dfppoi_tcdxa1_t                                                      r_q01
r_q03        super_0/cbo_bqibif0_t                                                      ntb0
r_q0367        super_top_0/nbio_nbif0_t                                                      nbif4
```

Actual output:

```
r_q01        smip_sc_rq0_t                                                    r_uq02
r_q02        super_path77/dfpp_tcdxa1_t                                       umc3
r_q02        super_path3/dfppoi_tcdxa1_t                                      r_q01
r_q03        super_0/cbo_bqibif0_t                                            ntb0
r_q0367       super_top_0/nbio_nbif0_t                                        nbif4
```

How to fix my code to get the actual output.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: @Paulo I think `My output:` in the question is actually the "actual output" while `Actual output:` is actually the "desired output".

Comment: @Kavitha Why set `FS`? There are no individual blanks nor tabs in your sample input so wouldn't the the default FS which separates by any white space work just fine? Do you **really** want the 2nd field in the last line of output to be indented 1 blank char more than the lines above it? If so explain the logic, if not fix your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is for your fields to line up, try `printf` with left-justification of set field widths, such as -

```
$: awk '{ printf "%-10s%-32s%s\n", $1,$2,$3 }' test
r_q01     smip_sc_rq0_t                   r_uq02
r_q02     super_path77/dfpp_tcdxa1_t      umc3
r_q02     super_path3/dfppoi_tcdxa1_t     r_q01
r_q03     super_0/cbo_bqibif0_t           ntb0
r_q0367   super_top_0/nbio_nbif0_t        nbif4
```

I have the field width as 10, 32, and the last field as ever it is; tweak to your needs. The dash after the `%` left-justifies.

Answer (score 4):

Use a tab as `OFS` and pipe output of `awk` to `column -t` to get tabular output:

```
awk -F ' {2,}' -v OFS='\t' '{$1=$1} 1' file | column -t
```

```
r_q01    smip_sc_rq0_t                r_uq02
r_q02    super_path77/dfpp_tcdxa1_t   umc3
r_q02    super_path3/dfppoi_tcdxa1_t  r_q01
r_q03    super_0/cbo_bqibif0_t        ntb0
r_q0367  super_top_0/nbio_nbif0_t     nbif4
```

Comment: The OP is using 2+blanks as their FS so either a) they don't need that, or b) their data can contain individual blanks, and/or c) their data can contain tabs. If "c" is true then setting OFS to a tab will end up breaking fields that contain tabs into separate fields. I've posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63599359/need-to-print-the-columns-in-same-order-using-awk#comment112464282_63599359) for the OP about that. I suspect what you have is the right answer but setting FS isn't necessary (i.e. "a") but we'll see.

Comment: Sure good point Ed. OP can use `awk -F ' {2,}' -v OFS='\3' '{$1=$1} 1' f | column -t -s $'\3'` if `\t` can be found anywhere in data (assuming control character `\3` is not present in input)

Comment: I love that this also dynamically sizes the output based on the largest value in any field, without you having to manually account for it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a generic solution, where not hard-coding the number of spaces. This will calculate the highest length of 1st and 2nd field elements and then will fill the spaces after 1st and 2nd fields accordingly. This will equal the space among 1st, 2nd and 3rd fields.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  first=(first>=length($1)?first:length($1))
  second=(second>=length($2)?second:length($2))
  next
}
{
  diff1=first-length($1)-1
  $1=sprintf("%-"first"s", $1)
  diff2=second-length($2)-1
  $2=sprintf("%-"second"s", $2)
  diff1=diff2=0
}
1
'  Input_file Input_file
```